# Expand/Collapse includes comments outside of scope?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two blocks of code with some comments. I want to comment and collapse one block of code, so that I can just run the 2nd block.

I commented the first block, and now I see the plus sign (+) in the SQL Server 2012 IDE. The issue is that by collapsing it, it will also include the comment from the second block (the one that begins with `/* Table 2 Delete ...`)

I tried changing the "Table 2" comment to `--` but it still includes it in the expand/collapse of the first block.

What can be done?

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find that works is to put something executable between the comment blocks.